# how to include files based on order of inheritance

Tags: php

I have a list of files, wherein a file is inherting another file ion the same directory. I want to include all files of a directory, how do I do it in the order of inheritance so that I dont get any errors

Comment: Unless your parse the files, you cannot do that automatically. Just include all the files, and see if you get any error. Then change the order until you don't have any error anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating dependencies yourself, you might as well use auto loading using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register).

This way your dependencies get worked out as required. A bit like "Just-In-Time" loading :)

Answer (score 0):

If your file/s have certain dependencies on other files, make sure you include the "parent" file/s first.

For example, you have a class A in a file A.php:

```
 <?php

    class A {
      // .. statements
    }
```

And you have a class B that extends A named B.php:

```
 <?php

   require_once( "A.php" );
   class B extends A {
     // .. statements
   }
```

The idea is to "include"/"require" the needed files first prior to using any functions/classes/statement in that file. In PHP 5, you can use the auto-loading functions that would "automatically" add/include the file you need without the constant need of typing require functions.

Answer (score 0):

You **COULD** use a parser to chek for dependecies but this would be a awfull lot of work and a real performance killer.

You could sort the files and prefix them with numbers

```
001.init.php
002.db_connect.php
003.pre_filters.php
```

But if you sort them manually it is rather pointles to rely on the file names.

If you have class inheritance you can combine a autoloader and require once.
Register an custom autoloader to require fles using require_once and and include all your files with a loop. If you need a class from the 8th file in your 4th file the autoloader will load the 8th file ahead of time and when your inlude loop reaches the 8th file nothing will happen because require_once will not include the file again.

But as you might already have realized:
Including files which are depending on each other in a random order from the file system is **NOT** a good idead.